# How to access SSH certificates from Azure DevOps Secure Files inside deployment pipeline?

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-devops

I am currently struggling with Azure DevOps. I am trying to deploy a VM through the DevOps pipeline and pass it the SSH key that I have saved in the Library as a Secure File.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- group: 'deployment-test'

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Create VM"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: sp-test1234
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az vm create \
      --resource-group testrg23142 \
      --name testvm \
      --image Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-LTS:latest \
      --custom-data "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"/cloud-init.yaml \
      --ssh-key-values ............
      --vnet-name vm-test-vnet \
      --subnet vm-test-subnet \
      --assign-identity '[system]'
```

I can´t find an example how to get my public key ¨test43.pub¨ from Secure File passed to ssh-key-values. Maybe there is something fundamental I am missing. I found the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=azure-devops which is about making the secure file accessible to the agent machine. The agent machine should be the temporary VM defined in pool, which has nothing to do with the VM I am creating. I am stuck, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [set a secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?tabs=yaml%2Cbatch&view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true#secret-variables) in your pipeline for the contents of your `mykey.pub` file. Then, call the variable in your pipeline definition as `$(myPubKey)`. For the secret part of your key, use the Secure File library in Azure Pipelines.

Here's a more specific example for using an SSH key:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops